# How to redirect two different ports using Apache httpd?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, httpd.conf

I setup SSL to my web application. Standard port for this application is 8080, and SSL port is 8443. I have a problem with Apache httpd configuration. I want to redirect all urls listed below:

```
http://1.2.3.4:8080
https://1.2.3.4:8080
http://1.2.3.4:8443
```

to this url:

```
https://1.2.3.4:8443
```

I changed httpd.conf to this:

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName 1.2.3.4
    Redirect "/" "https://1.2.3.4:8443"
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine for the first url listed above, but it does not for other urls. I tried different configurations but they did not work. Can anyone help with me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> https://1.2.3.4:8080
> http://1.2.3.4:8443
> ```

If HTTP is being served on port 8080 and HTTPS (SSL) is on 8443 then neither of the above URLs will be accessible in order to be able to trigger a redirect. (?!)

In your config HTTP is *only* port 8080 and HTTPS is *only* port 8443.

Reference:
https://serverfault.com/questions/359461/apache-answer-both-http-and-https-on-the-same-port

Comment: Ok, you are right, I understand. But is there any way to redirect `http://1.2.3.4:8443` to `https://10.200.200.91:8443` when httpd listens on port 8080?

Comment: The HTTP redirect only occurs _after_ the request has resolved on your server. If HTTP is listening on port 8080, then a request like `http://1.2.3.4:8443` is simply never going to resolve correctly and the browser will timeout. In order to do what you require, you would need Apache to answer to HTTP on ports 8080 _and_ 8443 (which is already shared with SSL?) - this is not possible with Apache AFAIK. I think this might be possible with some kind of front end proxy that could intercept and divert such requests?

Answer (score 0):

Configure mod_rewrite in your httpd.conf to achieve such a redirect

For example:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module  modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:8080>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
LoadModule rewrite_module  modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =8080
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:8443/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: The first example code doesn't work for me. The second one does the same what my code from the first post.

Comment: All you've done here is implement a standard HTTP to HTTPS (temporary) redirect, that's not what the OP is asking for.